# Order Only Nested Model Data Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, columnsorting

I am trying to order only the nested include Scheme Model based on an integer column but it seems like the code is not working. Also, the data is being fetched from `MYSQL` bottom to up and shown as output.

sample code:

```
[err, products] = await to(
Product_Inventory_Mapping.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Product,
      as: "product_details",
      where: filterClause,
      include: [
        {
          model: Unit,
          as: "unit_details"
        },
        {
          model: Brand,
          as: "brand_details"
        },
        {
          model: Category,
          as: "category_details"
        },
        {
          model: Sub_Brand,
          as: "sub_brand_details"
        },
        {
          model: Sub_Category,
          as: "sub_category_details"
        },
        {
          model: Brand_Company,
          as: "brand_company_details"
        },
        {
          model: Scheme,
          as: "schemes",
          attributes: [`moq`, 'discount', `description`],
          order: [[{ model: Scheme, as: "schemes" }, "moq", "ASC"]],
          where: {
            status: 1
          },
          required: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  order: [
    [{ model: Product, as: "product_details" }, "mrp", "ASC"]
  ],
  where: {
    user_id: aligned_distributors,
    brand_company_id: filtered_brand_company,
    count: {
      [Op.gt]: 0
    },
    sp: {
      [Op.gt]: 0
    }
  },
  attributes: [
    `product_id`,
    "user_id",
    "count",
    "sp",
    "occ",
    "brand_company_id"
  ],
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  subQuery: false
}));
```

Here I want to order only the data inside the Scheme Model. 
Sample response:

```
"products": [
    {
        "product_id": 115,
        "user_id": 1003,
        "count": 50,
        "sp": 9.09,
        "occ": 9.09,
        "brand_company_id": 11,
        "product_details": {
            "id": 115,
            "category_id": 2,
            "sub_category_id": 12,
            "brand_company_id": 11,
            "brand_id": 24,
            "sub_brand_id": 44,
            "sku_code": null,
            "min_order_qty": "27",
            "description": "Nandini Butter Milk Tetra Pack, 200 Ml",
            "unit_id": 4,
            "weight": "200ml",
            "mrp": "10.00",
            "barcode": "",
            "image_url": "https://xxxxxx.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/products/1565919229Unknown-min-5.jpg",
            "created_at": "2019-08-12T13:44:01.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-15T20:03:49.000Z",
            "unit_details": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Pieces",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "brand_details": {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "Nandini Butter Milk",
                "brand_company_id": 11,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "category_details": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Packaged Food",
                "image_url": "https://zzzz.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/category/food-min.png",
                "created_at": "2019-08-11T11:36:52.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-11T11:36:52.000Z"
            },
            "sub_brand_details": {
                "id": 44,
                "name": "Nandini Butter Milk",
                "brand_id": 24,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "sub_category_details": {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Dairy products (Butter, Cheese etc)",
                "category_id": 2,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "brand_company_details": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka Co-operative Milk Producers",
                "image_url": "https://xxxxx.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/company/kmf_logo.jpg",
                "created_at": "2019-08-12T13:10:18.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-12T13:10:18.000Z"
            },
            "schemes": [
                {
                    "moq": 30,
                    "discount": 1.5,
                    "description": "8 % offer"
                },
                {
                    "moq": 20,
                    "discount": 1,
                    "description": "20 % offer"
                },
                {
                    "moq": 40,
                    "discount": 2,
                    "description": "40 % offer"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
```

In the database, the Scheme data is saved as:
[image]

Scheme belongs to the Product via product_id. I want the Scheme array to be sorted by `moq ASC` so that the value comes in order of moq: `20 > 30 > 40`.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, an `order` clause in the included model doesn't work.  But, you can make a reference to the included model in the main model.  I think this should work if you combine your two `order` clauses into one:

```
Product_Inventory_Mapping.findAll({
include: [
  ..... lots of includes here ....
],      
order: [
        [{ model: Product, as: "product_details" }, "mrp", "ASC"],
        [{ model: Scheme, as: "schemes" }, "moq", "ASC"]]
      ],
```

This will order by moq within mrp... you could remove the first field if you really want to sort ONLY by moq....